# d3 Bubble chart - render live data

Tags: d3.js

I am using d3 Bubble chart.

http://bl.ocks.org/phuonghuynh/raw/54a2f97950feadb45b07/

In this plugin when i add more data for example 20 data:

```
data: {
  items: [
    {text: "Java", count: "236"},
    {text: ".Net", count: "382"},
    {text: "Php", count: "170"},
    {text: "Ruby", count: "123"},
    {text: "D", count: "12"},
    {text: "Python", count: "170"},
    {text: "C/C++", count: "32"},
    {text: "Pascfdddddal", count: "10"},
    {text: "excel", count: "30"},
    {text: "excel1", count: "30"},
    {text: "excel2", count: "30"},
    {text: "Something", count: "170"},
  ],
  eval: function (item) {return item.count;},
  classed: function (item) {return item.text.split(" ").join("");}
}
```

It's not working without error. the page loading long time.

I have 2 Questions:

1. more than 15 data it's not working.
2. When i click the any bubble need to load the new data using Ajax.Its possible?

I added my code in Jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/uXn2p/143/

Comment: Using the data in your post it works fine, what is the failure mode?

Comment: @CoolBlue If you add some 10 dummy data in the current JSON array provided above it will hangup. My hunch its a problem with the plugin RSKMR is using..

Comment: @CoolBlue, Yes. If I add some more 10 dummy data in that json array means the page loading long time without error.